# How to start previous successful release automatically in Devops/VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-devops-extensions, devops-services

If the current release has failed and how to run the previous successful release automatically?

[image]

Ex: If A(Current release) has failed then automatically trigger B(Previous success release) release. Trigger from another release definition.

Comment: Now, we have 2 release definition, one is **DefiniA** and another is **DefiniB**.  Now, you'd like to trigger B(Previous success release) from **DefiniB** once A is failed, right?

Comment: Yes, correct @Merlin Liang - MSFT

Comment: This would be very complex(BUT can be achieved). One furthur question, why you are looking for such complecated approach to trigger B? Do you have any concern?

Comment: This approach for the first deploy web app pipeline, second Web API and the last one is DB script.  so last DB Script has failed means rollback the last successful release in Web App and Web API deployment.

Comment: Copy that. So web app, web api and DB script deployments are separate pipeline definitions? Or they are deployed with one release definition(different stage)? I would expect to find an easier approach for your scenario.

Comment: web app, web api and DB script deployments are used separate pipeline definitions. not used the different stage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222213/discussion-between-suresh-and-merlin-liang-msft).

Answer (score 5):

No need to be so complicated to use powershell to call api. We have built-in feature can achieve your requirement. Since release pipeline consists of one or more stages，re-deploy release pipeline can be considered as re-running stages.

So open the release pipeline definition first. Then navigate to **Post-deployment conditions** of the stage => Enable **Auto-redeploy trigger** => Select the **Event** and the **action**:

[image]

See the actual execution result:

[image]

This is the advantage of the Azure Devops so that you don't need to worry if some thing goes wrong during the Prod deployments as the tool will automatically reverse the last successful deployment by its own.

Updated:

```
$connectionToken="{PAT}" 

$url="https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/release/releases?api-version=6.0"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))
    
$Body=@"
{
  "definitionId": {specific release definition id},
  "description": "Creating release from powershell",
  "artifacts": [
    {
      "alias": "{artifact name}",
      "instanceReference": {
        "id": "{buildid}",
        "name": null
      }
    }
  ],
  "isDraft": false,
  "reason": "none",
  "manualEnvironments": null
}
"@
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $Body -ContentType application/json
```

Comment: @Suresh, Re-run the release pipeline, isn't it rerun the stage job in the pipeline?

Comment: @Suresh. Welcome. Really hope this could resolve your puzzle. Feel free to leave comment if you still has any puzzle on this approach. :-)

Comment: How to trigger one release to another release definition for the last success deploy?

Comment: @Suresh Is this triggered release the specific one? Have fixed definition id?

Comment: Yes trigger specific one with a definition id, but not trigger last success release

Comment: @Suresh, We do not have built-in feature can do this. You have to achieve that via powershell script. See my updated.

Comment: Created sample release and execute the above script, but still not trigger the last successful release.

Comment: @Suresh, In your previous comment, you mentioned that not trigger last success release. So I need confirm that whether you need trigger the last successful release of specific pipeline, or just re-run the specific pipeline?

Comment: Not a specific release, need to trigger check all release with based on a specific definition id

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to achieve this and you need to use REST API.

1. First you need to get last succeeded deployments. For that you should use [this endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/deployments/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0).

```
GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{{organization}}/{{project}}/_apis/release/deployments?definitionId=7&api-version=6.1-preview.2
```

You need to parse response in powershell to get your release id and other details.

2. Once you have details from above endpoint you need to create a new release with those details. (So far I haven't found an endpoint to run again already created release)
   To create release you need to call [this endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#uri-parameters):

```
POST https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/fabrikam/MyFirstProject/_apis/release/releases?api-version=6.0
```

Here is an example body

```
{
  "definitionId": 1,
  "description": "Creating Sample release",
  "artifacts": [
    {
      "alias": "Fabrikam.CI",
      "instanceReference": {
        "id": "2",
        "name": null
      }
    }
  ],
  "isDraft": false,
  "reason": "none",
  "manualEnvironments": null
}
```

Details of artifacts you will find in response of first endpoint.

Here is an example how you may call REST API from task

```bsh
$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/thecodemanual/DevOps Manual/_apis/build/builds/$(Build.BuildId)/timeline?api-version=5.1"

Write-Host $uri

# Invoke the REST call
$build = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"} -ContentType "application/json"

$taskResult = $build.records | Where-Object {$_.name -eq "ConditionalStep" } | Select-Object result

Write-Host $taskResult.result
```

Comment: I have used the above powershell script but $build response is showing empty like @{count=0; value=System.Object[]}

Comment: Did you change my definition id `definitionId=7`?

Comment: Yes changed definition id, but not trigger last success release

Comment: To run an already created release you can make a PATCH request to "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/nsudeep/ADO-Cloud-tesing/_apis/release/releases/{releaseID}/environments/{environemntID}?api-version=6.0"  with a body stating "status": "inProgress"